# Erro ao criar tabela

Tags: mariadb

Tenho uma tabela usuários e uma tabela amizade, um amigo também é um usuário e quando eu adicionar um usuário como amigo ele também tem que ser meu amigo, agora que o conceito está claro, gostaria de saber como faço para criar essa tabela, pois está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postagens(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    u_id                INT,
    titulo              VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    conteudo            VARCHAR(4096),
    imagem              VARCHAR(256),
    audio               VARCHAR(256),
    video               VARCHAR(256),
    CONSTRAINT id_pk    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT u_id_fk  FOREIGN KEY(u_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS amizade(
    id                  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    u_id                INT,
    a_id                INT,
    CONSTRAINT id_pk    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT u_id_fk  FOREIGN KEY(u_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id),
    CONSTRAINT a_id_fk  FOREIGN KEY(a_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: É mysql ou mariadb ?

Comment: Desculpe, o conceito ainda não está muito claro. Poderia explicar melhor: **um amigo também é um usuário e quando eu adicionar um usuário como amigo ele também tem que ser meu amigo**.  
Adicionalmente, você pode colocar na pergunta a estrutura da tabela `usuarios`?

Comment: eu nao tenho como testar mySql aqui, apenas com Sql server... se eu executo isso em S.Server ele dá erro se eu não criar a primary key na tabela usuarios. Na sua tem?

Comment: desculpe andreia, não entendi!

Comment: RBZ é mariadb, mas tem alguma diferença?

Comment: O que tem mais nesse db? Eu testei o query aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, você deve estar duplicando algo como diz no erro, já deve ter alguma outra tabela utilizando das chaves

Comment: Creio que a tabela amizade já existe e você ao invés de cria-la, pretende adicionar/mudar algum campo

Comment: eu quis dizer se voce criou a PRIMARY KEY na usa tabela Usuarios

Comment: @DanrleyFernandesLopes, as tags são para determinar exatamente o seu cenário. Se colocar tags que não são relacionadas, sim, podem ter diferenças dependendo do contexto.

Comment: Algumas diferenças por novas funções: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-features/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome da foreign key que você definiu como `u_id_fk` já está declarado na tabela `postagens`. Nome de **foreign key** é única, independente de tabela. Crie outro nome para `u_id_fk` na tabela `amizade`.

> Você receberá esta mensagem se estiver tentando adicionar uma
>   restrição com um nome que já tenha sido usado em outro lugar.
>   Se a tabela que você está tentando criar inclui uma restrição de chave
>   estrangeira e você forneceu **seu próprio nome para essa restrição**,
>   lembre-se de que ela deve ser exclusiva no banco de dados.

Uma boa prática de criação de foreign keys é sempre ter uma padrão de nomenclatura, exemplo:

```
fk_<TABLE_NAME>_<FOREIGN_KEY_COLUMN_NAME>
```

Para verificar as restrições existentes no banco de dados MySQL/Mariadb, use a seguinte consulta SQL:

```
SELECT
    constraint_name,
    table_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE
    constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND table_schema = DATABASE()
ORDER BY
    constraint_name;
```

Fonte da resposta: [ERRO: Erro 1005: não é possível criar tabela (errno: 121)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12623651/6510304)